# Join multiple tables with partial same column values by table priority (Take all Table A, join all Table not in A, join all Table C not in A or B)

Tags: oracle, join, rank

I have 3 tables in an Oracle DB with different up-to-dateness depending on delivery status.

Each table has a few columns that are the same by value (but not by name) and some columns that are specific to that table (e.g. size split into 3 columns == "length", "width", "height" VS. a single column with "lengthXwidthXheight").

I need to be able to select specific columns from each table. If a table doesn't have that column it can be "NONE / empty in the end result.

Table1:

```
orderid | name | table1 | table2 | ...
1       | a    | ...    | ...    | ...
None    | b    | ...    | ...    | ...
2       | c    | ...    | ...    | ...
```

Table 2:

```
orderid | name | table1 | count | ...
1       | a    | ...    | ...   | ...
None    | k    | ...    | ...   | ...
4       | d    | ...    | ...   | ...
```

Table 3:

```
orderid | name | table1 | place | ...
1       | a    | ...    | ...   | ...
None    | u    | ...    | ...   | ...
4       | p    | ...    | ...   | ...
7       | t    | ...    | ...   | ...
```

I want to join all 3 tables on orderid in a specific order.

Priority is: Table1 > Table2 > Table3

- Select all entries from Table1 where "orderid != None"
- Select all entries from Table2 where "orderid != None" and where "orderid" is not already existing from Table1
- Select all entries from Table3 where "orderid != None" and where "orderid" is not already existing from Table1 or Table2

So the end table should look like:

```
orderid | name | table1 | table2 |count | place
1       | a    | ...    | ...    | ...  | ...
2       | c    | ...    | ...    | ...  | ... 
4       | d    | ...    | ...    | ...  | ... 
7       | t    | ...    | ...    | ...  | ...
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `UNION` and not a `JOIN`.

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to check if the rows in `table2` or `table3` are duplicates of the rows of the previous in priority tables:

```
select t1.* from table1 t1 where t1.orderid <> 'None'
union -- or union all
select t2.* from table2 t2
where t2.orderid <> 'None'
and not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.orderid = t2.orderid)
union -- or union all
select t3.* from table3 t3
where t3.orderid <> 'None'
and not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.orderid = t3.orderid)
and not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.orderid = t3.orderid)
```

And another way to do it with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select t.orderid, t.name, .... 
from (
  select u.*, row_number() over (partition by u.orderid order by u.tbl) rn
  from (
    select 1 tbl, t1.* from table1 t1 where t1.orderid <> 'None'
    union all
    select 2 tbl, t2.* from table2 t2 where t2.orderid <> 'None'
    union all
    select 3 tbl, t3.* from table3 t3 where t3.orderid <> 'None'
  ) u
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5e735dbc3a95d7cc91344bbe5e80783e).
Results:

```
> orderid | name
> :------ | :---
> 1       | a   
> 2       | c   
> 4       | d   
> 7       | t
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention that some columns in each table are the same (at least from the value, not the name) and some are different. I need to select a few specific columns from each table (e.g. one has size split in 3 columns - length, width, height, one has size in a single column (lengthXwidthXheight). UNION throws me a "query block has incorrect number of result columns.

Comment: Then you will have to enumerate all the columns instead of t1.* and create fake columns as null in the place of the columns that are missing from one table but exist in the other tables (and in the correct order). There is no other way to get a resultset like the one that you want.

Comment: How can I create fake columns as NULL?

Comment: For example if a column like `columnonlyintable2` exists only in table2 and you want it 3d in the results then: `select t1.orderid, t1.name, null columnonlyintable2, ... from table1 t1.... union all select t2.orderid, t2.name, t2.columnonlyintable2, ... from table2 t2 union all select t3.orderid, t3.name, null columnonlyintable2, ... from table3 t3....` By setting `null` in tables table1 and table3 in the place of the column you create a fake null column. This must be done for all columns that are not common in all 3 tables. The name of the fake column will be fetched from table1.

Answer (score 0):

You need `full outer joins` here:

```sql
select
   coalesce(t1.orderid,t3.orderid,t3.orderid) as coalesce_orderid,
   coalesce(t1.name,t2.name,t3.name) as coalesce_name,
   t1.name as name1,
   t2.name as name2,
   t3.name as name3
from
    Table1 t1
    full join Table2 t2
        on t1.orderid=t2.orderid
    full join Table3 t3
        on nvl(t1.orderid,t2.orderid)=t3.orderid;
```

If you want to exclude order='None', you can add

`where coalesce(t1.orderid,t3.orderid,t3.orderid)!='None'`

Full example with sample data:

```sql
with
Table1(orderid, name) as (
select '1'       ,'a' from dual union all
select 'None'    ,'b' from dual union all
select '2'       ,'c' from dual
)
,Table2(orderid, name) as (
select '1'       ,'a' from dual union all
select 'None'    ,'k' from dual union all
select '4'       ,'d' from dual
)
,Table3(orderid, name) as (
select '1'       ,'a' from dual union all
select 'None'    ,'u' from dual union all
select '4'       ,'p' from dual union all
select '7'       ,'t' from dual
)
select
   coalesce(t1.orderid,t3.orderid,t3.orderid) as coalesce_orderid,
   coalesce(t1.name,t2.name,t3.name) as coalesce_name,
   t1.name as name1,
   t2.name as name2,
   t3.name as name3
from
    Table1 t1
    full join Table2 t2
        on t1.orderid=t2.orderid
    full join Table3 t3
        on nvl(t1.orderid,t2.orderid)=t3.orderid;
```

Results:

```
COALESCE_ORDERID   COALESCE_NAME      NAME1 NAME2 NAME3
------------------ ------------------ ----- ----- -----
1                  a                  a     a     a
None               b                  b     k     u
4                  d                        d     p
2                  c                  c
7                  t                              t
```